# Mac cached routing? (traceroute)

Tags: macos, networking

So I got a problem regarding access to my website. Whenever I run traceroute on my computer it returns the correct traceroute to the correct site. However when I run it on someone elses pc it gives a completely different traceroute but wrong traceroute (an old one).

Some info that might help:
- My PC: Windows
- His PC: Mac

We both loaded the sites a few times before and he is still on the old traceroute from a couple of months back.

I already tried clearing the DNS server of Mac OS X, Rebooting it, Clearing browser cache (even a full reset of the browsers) and still it is not loading in any of the browsers.

Comment: Do you mean they get an old IP address for your web site? If not, what do you mean by a "an old one"? If so, why bring routing into it?

Comment: Yes they get an old IP address from it

Answer (score 0):

if IP address of remote website is different, try to manually set DNS server to check if it solves the problem
static DNS can be changed with nslookup (windows, maybe on mac also)
you can set manual DNS by the 'server' command in nslookup prompt :

```
C:\Users\me>nslookup
Default Server:  nfdns.bezeqint.net
Address:  192.117.235.235

> www.stackoverflow.com
# this is my dns
Server:  nfdns.bezeqint.net
Address:  192.117.235.235

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    stackoverflow.com
Addresses:  104.16.37.249
# changing dns server
> server 1.2.3.4
Default Server:  [1.2.3.4]
Address:  1.2.3.4
# now can check again with the new dns
> www.stackoverflow.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found it, I overlooked the /etc/hosts file, so there was still an error in it. Thanks for helping!